# Separate file for html in SPFX

Tags: spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric

I am new to SPFX ad I am trying to create a separate file for my html code which I have done by doing `this.domElement.innerHTML = require("./Index.html");`

But I am not able to get the design that earlier exist.

**Index.html**

`<div class="${ styles.softLoan }">
    <div class="${ styles.container }">
      <div class="${ styles.row }">
        <div class="${ styles.column }">
          <span class="${ styles.title }">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
          <p class="${ styles.subTitle }">Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
          <p class="${ styles.description }">${escape(this.properties.description)}</p>
          <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" class="${ styles.button }">
            <span class="${ styles.label }">Learn more</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`

What do I need to do so that officeUiFabric design work fine?